# Bootstrap 3: Adjust size of cells in div row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I adjust the size of cells in a row such that their heights are equal and all the characters fit in them? This is how a row looks like right now:
[image]
Note the small characters in the Japanese column. The cell is not tall enough to accommodate them. Also, the height of the cell in the English column is less than that of the one next to it.

I want the row to look like this:
[image]

The background looks like a long, green rectangle.

Here is my CSS and HTML code:

```
<style type='text/css'>
/* For small screen */
  .row :nth-child(even){
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.row :nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #D0E9C6;
}

/* For medium screen */    
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row :nth-child(4n), .row :nth-child(4n-1) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .row :nth-child(4n-2), .row :nth-child(4n-3) {
    background-color: #D0E9C6;
  }
}

/* For large screen */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row :nth-child(6n), .row :nth-child(6n-1), .row :nth-child(6n-2) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .row :nth-child(6n-3), .row :nth-child(6n-4), .row :nth-child(6n-5) {
    background-color: #D0E9C6;
  }
}

.header, h1 { background-color: #FFFFFF !important}
.en-buffer  { margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 10px }
.jp-buffer  { margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 header jp-buffer"><h1>Japanese</h1></div><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 header en-buffer"><h1>English</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 japanese jp-buffer"><ruby lang="jp">カレー</ruby><ruby lang="jp">粉<rp>(</rp><rt>こ</rt><rp>)</rp>は</ruby><ruby lang="jp">家<rp>(</rp><rt>いえ</rt><rp>)</rp>にあるの?</ruby></div><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 english en-buffer">Do you have curry powder at your house?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is one of the possible solutions: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

Comment: Could you color the row background, rather than the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem was the classes `.en-buffer` and `.jp-buffer`

try using `padding` **instead** `margin`...

```css
/* For small screen */

.row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #D0E9C6;
}
/* For medium screen */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row:nth-child(4n),
  .row:nth-child(4n-1) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .row:nth-child(4n-2),
  .row:nth-child(4n-3) {
    background-color: #D0E9C6;
  }
}
/* For large screen */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row:nth-child(6n),
  .row:nth-child(6n-1),
  .row:nth-child(6n-2) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .row:nth-child(6n-3),
  .row:nth-child(6n-4),
  .row:nth-child(6n-5) {
    background-color: #D0E9C6;
  }
}
.header,
h1 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important
}
.en-buffer {
  padding: 10px;
}
.jp-buffer {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 header ">
    <h1>Japanese</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 header ">
    <h1>English</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 jp-buffer ">
    <ruby lang="jp">カレー</ruby>
    <ruby lang="jp">粉
      <rp>(</rp>
      <rt>こ</rt>
      <rp>)</rp>は</ruby>
    <ruby lang="jp">家
      <rp>(</rp>
      <rt>いえ</rt>
      <rp>)</rp>にあるの?</ruby>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 en-buffer">Do you have curry powder at your house?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BJ Peter DeLaCruz hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, @Alvaro! It did. :-)